# MediaPlayer.reset() same as release() with respect to resource management

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Scenario:

Suppose media player is playing a track and user clicks on some other track to play.

So which of the below approach is better with respect to resource management:

**1. Release:**

```
mMediaPlayer.stop();
if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    mMediaPlayer = null;
}
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mOnErrorListener);
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);
```

**2. Reset**

```
mMediaPlayer.reset();
```

I want to know does both approaches are same or one is better over other?

Answer (score 2):

`Reset` the **MediaPlayer** is the better option

```
mMediaPlayer.reset();
```

If you `Release` the **MediaPlayer** in that case after releasing u have to create `MediaPlayer's` Object again.

After `Reset` or `Release` you have to follow these steps.

1. Initialize
2. Prepare
3. Start
   [image]

Extra thing is you create `MediaPlayer's Object` multiple time

So, better option is to `Reset the MediaPlayer`
because you are creating `Object of MediaPlayer single time`.

Comment: And, there will be no effect on the memory that media player is using, since it is not refreshed?

Comment: reset will use less resource than release